# ASP.NET Java Web Service HTTP Request Error

Tags: java, c#, asp.net, apache, web-services

I'm working on a web application developed by using ASP.NET (C#) and we are using a web service developed by Java

I've published it to apache and I want to call it using `HTTPWebRequest` but when trying to call it I have this exception:

> Internal Server Error - 500 : Java heap Space

Comment: I've installed apache tomcat server and deployed web service on it on a specific port then call it normally using httpwebrequest. The estimated response is XML response that I know how to handle it

Comment: Strangely, seems that you're getting out of memory in your Java service. Do you know how much memory have you dedicate to the server hosting your Java web service?

Comment: 1 GB is memory size allocated to Java

Comment: Then there's something wrong in the implementation of your Java web service, unless you're trying to retrieve too much data in a single request.